# getting data from Web Services c#

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue loading data in the correct format from web services.

Web Service code:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string LoadLearrner(string id)
    {
        MyFunctions func = new MyFunctions();
        DataSet ds;

        DataSet dtsta = SQLServer.GetDsBySP("Load_Learner_ForCRM","learnerId", id.ToString());
       
        string[] cntName = new string[dtsta.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow rdr in dtsta.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            list.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
            list.Add(rdr[1].ToString());
            list.Add(rdr[2].ToString());
            list.Add(rdr[3].ToString());
            list.Add(rdr[5].ToString());
            i++;
        }

        String[] str = list.ToArray();
        string JSONString=string.Empty;  
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str);  
        return JSONString;
    }
```

Code that's used to call the above web service method is:

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://abc/Company/CrmLearner.asmx/LoadLearrner?id=" + item.learner_id);
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.ContentType = "application/text";
            
                    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                    }
```

Result is:

[image]

I don't want the result like that. I want to load proper XML or JSON and store it in an object.

Comment: Do you have to use WebMethod? Can you use something else, perhaps a generic handler? Or better yet - Web API?

Comment: i am getting data from the old asp.net application. which was made in 2010.

Comment: Okay...and what about the other question I asked you?